# Symfony 5/Twig: How do I resolve "Key for array does not exist", although the key exists?

Tags: multidimensional-array, twig, symfony5

I am testing some code using a hexmap. I am reading map-data from the database and want to render the map. All worked well until I added a key=>value pair in a method. It looks like this:

```php
function map_render() {
    // The following line retrieves an array with the map data. An array sample:
    // $map = array(
    //            array(“id"=>"0",
    //                  "coord_y=>"0",
    //                  "coord_x=>"0"),
    //            array("id"=>"1",
    //                  ...)
    //        )
    $map = $this->findMap();

    // [some code to determine $map_width and $map_height]

    for ($x=0; $x<$map_width; $x++) {
        $coord_x = $x;
        for ($y=0; $y<$map_height; $y++) {
            $coord_y = $y;
            
            // [some code to determine $display_x and $display_y)

            // Styles to position image correctly
            $style = sprintf("left:%dpx;top:%dpx", $display_x, $display_y);

            // Add style information to each element in the $map array
            // 'style' => $style should be added to all elements
            foreach ($map as $key => $value) {
                if($map[$key]['coord_y'] == $coord_y and $map[$key]['coord_x'] == $coord_x) {
                    $map[$key]['style'] = $style;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $map;
}
```

The controller merely passes the map-array to the template:

```php
public function map() {
    $this->data['Map'] = $this->map->map_render();

    return $this->render('map/index.html.twig', [
        'data' => $this->data,
    ]);
}
```

In Twig I output this like so:

```html
// Testing the "style" key
{{ data.Map.0.style }}

{% for Map in data.Map %}
    <img
        src='{{ asset('images/map/' ~ Map.id) }}.png'
        alt='{{ Map.coord_x }}/{{ Map.coord_y }}'
        style='{{ Map.style }}'
    >
{% endfor %}
```

Running this I get the following error:

> "Key "style" for array with keys "id, coord_x, coord_y" does not exist."

Yet a `{{ dump(data.Map) }}`  reveals that the "style" key indeed exists. The line `{{ data.Map.0.style }}` also outputs the "style" value.

If I comment out the line `style='{{ Map.style }}'` everything works as intended.

Why is the for-loop not able to see the "style" key, although all other keys get rendered perfectly fine?

Comment: Probably one or more records don't have the `style` key or the value of `style` is `null`. Adjust your code to `style="{{ Map.Style|default }}`

Comment: Nice! I was unaware of the "default" filter. You are right. There are some empty "styles" (for a reason I can now sit and figure out :-). Thank you. This had me stumped for a while now.